# get the value of a NSString variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have a weird problem. 
pictureLink is a global variable declared in .h

```
 NSString *pictureLink;
}
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSString *pictureLink;
```

i wrote this code

```
NSString * myPictureUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.com/uploads/%@.jpg",hash];
pictureLink=myPictureUrl;
```

I have a strange result, it must be a pointer
Or

```
pictureLink=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.com/uploads/%@.jpg",hash];
```

i have EXC_BAD_ACESS error

Comment: If possible use ARC, then the compiler will handle all the retain counts behind the scenes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's memory management fault, you're not retaining `myPictureUrl` in your code.

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.com/uploads/%@.jpg",hash];` returns an autoreleased value, so you have two options:

1. `pictureLink=myPictureUrl;` should look like `[self setPictureLink:myPictureUrl];`.
2. do a `[myPictureUrl retain];`, and don't forget to `release` it later.

Consider using ARC (Automatic Retain Counting) for you project. With ARC the compiler takes care of retain counts so you don't have to, in fact aren't allowed to. There is a refactoring that will convert a current project.

Comment: If there is a property do not code around it, use the property setters/getters. Assigning directly to `pictureLink` will create a memory leak of the object currently pointed  to by `pictureLink`.

Comment: @Andrey thank you work perfect. It's my first app and i never release object :D it will cause me  problems?

Comment: @Mehdi: sure, you need to release all your `retain`/`strong` property ivars in `- (void) dealloc` method.

Answer (score 2):

You are bypassing your `@property` by calling directly the variable, so no `magic` provided by your `@property` settings is done, like retain and release.
you need to do `self.pictureLink` to use the `@property`.
To avoid the temptation of accessing directly my variable I do the following

```
NSString *theProperty
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *property;
```

and

```
@synthesise property = theProperty;
```

That way if I go around the `@property` I really, really wanted to do it.
But you need a very, very, very good reason to do so, and event then, it may not be a good enough reason.

Comment: @VinceBum Also by directly assigning to the ivar no release is done on any previous object it pointed to.

Comment: @CocoaFu, yes bypassing `@property` is bad.

Comment: More commonally an underscore "_" is used in place of "the". Ex: `@synthesise property = _property;`. But `theProperty` does work fine.

Comment: @CocoaFu yes I've seen that a lot recently, and I was wondering what as append of the Apple directive stating that they were using _property internally for there variable, so that we should avoid them to avoid possible conflict.

Comment: Prefixing ivars with an underscore is fine, any conflicts will be caught by the compiler. What is **not OK** is to prefix method names with an underscore. This is somewhat a change in best practices and you will occasionally see Apple sample code with ivars with a underscore prefix.